# In NSDateComponents, how do you know if it's AM or PM?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, time, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

When I use NSDateComponents, how do I know I'm setting a time as Am or Pm? Or is it 24-hour format? Here's the code:

```
NSDate *morningEnd = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *components1 = [gregorian components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:morningEnd];
[components1 setHour:11];
[components1 setMinute:59];
```

How do I know if I'm setting it as 11:59 AM or 11:59 PM?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The hour is defined out of 24 hours. 0 - 11 will be AM, 12 - 23 will be PM.

**Edit:**

Corrected my range to be 0 - 23 as per the comments below. Thanks guys for correcting me.

Comment: Is it really 1-based? 0-11 and 12-23 would make sense.

Comment: The answer is not correct. **The hour range is 0 .. 23** and not 1 .. 24, at least in my environment. It could be locale dependent, but I don't think so. Since your answer has already been accepted, it would be good if you could verify that and update the answer if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Martin. You were correct. I updated my answer to be correct.