# To do an action in a certain format

Tags: swift

I need to do some action in certain time. So, for example, I need to delete userDefaults at 6pm
How I need to do this? I made something like this

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Second], fromDate: date)

if components.hour == 6 && components.minute == 0 && components.second == 0 {
//
}
```

And how to choose certain format? For example, I need "pm"

Only swift, please. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In NSDateComponents, how do you know if it's AM or PM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042980/in-nsdatecomponents-how-do-you-know-if-its-am-or-pm)

Comment: Thanks you, sunshine!